# Parsing multiple dateTime strings into dateTime formats in xslt or TIBCO BW

Tags: date, datetime, xslt, xpath, tibco

Here is the format

```
<Record>
    <DateTime>2012-11-11T17:06:54</DateTime>
    <Description>Date1</Description>
</Record>
<Record>
    <DateTime>2012-11-11T17:06:54</DateTime>
    <Description>Date2</Description>
</Record>
<Record>
    <DateTime>2000-09-29T15:28:08</DateTime>
    <Description>Date3</Description>
</Record>
<Record>
    <DateTime>29-11-2012T14:35:53</DateTime>
    <Description>Date4</Description>
</Record>
    <Record>
    <DateTime>2000-09-29T15:28:10</DateTime>
    <Description>Date5</Description>
</Record>
```

I want them to parse into dateTime formats at once without using formats like "YY:MM:dd"...

I used before this format but I can't debug or send output because the fourth Record tag has different format as you can see in the example above  `<DateTime>29-11-2012T14:35:53</DateTime>`.

Does anyone know how can I solve this.. in the Activity input I used

```
$duration=xsd:dateTime(DateTime[1])
format-dateTime($duration,"[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]")
```

But it doesn't show me anything because of the `<DateTime>29-11-2012T14:35:53</DateTime>`.

I want output similar to this:

```
<Calendar>
    <Record>
        <DateTime>2000-09-29T15:28:07</DateTime>
        <Description>Date4</Description>
        <Difference>6476 Days 8 Hours 18 Minutes 48 Seconds</Difference>
    </Record>
</Calendar>
```

Comment: So what do you want to do with that `Record`, do you want to ignore it? You can certainly `match="Record[DateTime[1] castable as xs:dateTime]"`.

Comment: I have already make that <DateTime[1]> a dateTime,but i can not debug all of them becase one of them is still string...i don't know how can i use two formats at once or multiple formats to convert all the strings into dateTime

Comment: I tried to convert all of them in the XML Schema but it's not working neither

Comment: If you encounter 09-11-2009, is that 9th November or 11th September?

Comment: 9th November...

Comment: Is the posted output ("Output similar like this") the complete output? Why does it say "Date4" although the `<DateTime>2000-09-29T15:28:07</DateTime>` is taken from the input with `<Description>Date5</Description>`? Do you know which elements have the YYYY-MM-DD format and which the DD-MM-YYYY format?

Comment: Output above its just example..i need just one Record tag with the chldren nodes(for example the oldest Date wich is 2000-09-29T15:28:08 and his siblings) ..but i can't convert them all to dates..for example i used for-each in activity input in Mapper and he cannot take them all because 29-11-2012T14:35:53 is different format and it calulates as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`xsd:dateTime()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) function can only parse valid [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) dateTime formatted values.

You could test whether the value is [`castable as`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-castable) `xsd:dateTime`, and for those that are not, use a regex to test whether it matches known formats, and [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) with a regex and capture groups to construct a properly formatted ISO 8601 formatted dateTime value that can be parsed as `xsd:dateTime`:

```
if (DateTime castable as xsd:dateTime ) then 
  xsd:dateTime(DateTime) 
else 
  if (matches(DateTime, '\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\dT.*')) then 
    xsd:dateTime(replace(DateTime, '(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)(T.*)', '$3-$2-$1$4')) 
  else ()
```

You could add additional if/else blocks with other dateTime patterns that you want to support.

Once you can construct `xsd:dateTime` objects, then you can perform the desired calculations.